# Perform regex on an Angular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I have an angular expression in my html which returns some data:

```
      <span ng-SOMTHING="stripFirstLetters">
            {{thing.data}}
      </span>
```

At the minute, the data being returned has 5 letters at the beginning which I want to remove. Can I accomplish this with ng-pattern?

So in my controller, somthing like this:

```
      $scope.stripFirstLeters = /^\d{5}/;
```

I just want to know if what I'm trying to do is possible... Thanks!

Comment: ng-pattern is for input elements.

Comment: the regex would be `/^\d{5}/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

`ng-pattern` isn't a directive. Rather it is an argument of the `input` directive ([ref](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/docs/api/ng/directive/input)). Using it standalone would have no effect.

You can always accomplish the same result using a filter, with sample usage:

```
<span>{{ thing.data | strip5 }}</span>
```

The filter implementation itself would be trivial:

```
app.filter("strip5", function() {
    return function(x) {
        if( typeof(x) !== "string" || x.length < 5 ) return "";
        return x.substring(5);
    };
});
```

Comment: Trivial for you perhaps :) But thanks all the same, works a treat!

Comment: If I wanted to strip away all characters up to and including the first space, how would that filter operate?

Comment: Just replace the content of the filter function with code that does what you want, e.g. `var index = x.indexOf(" ");return x.substring(x+1);` with some error checking.